# Java Code for connection of alfresco through ftps

Tags: java, ftp, alfresco

Hi I m trying to connect our alfresco through FTP  But  I m getting Error Unknownhostexception

my code are following

```
public void FTPTest()throws SocketException, IOException
{

    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    System.out.println("1");
      ftp.connect("172.17.178.144:2121"); // or "localhost" in your case
      System.out.println("2");
      System.out.println("login: "+ftp.login("admin", "admin"));
      System.out.println("3");
      ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("folder/subfolder/");
      // list the files of the current directory
      FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();  
      System.out.println("Listed "+files.length+" files.");
      for(FTPFile file : files) {
       System.out.println(file.getName());
      }
       // lets pretend there is a JPEG image in the present folder that we want to copy to the desktop (on a windows machine)
      ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // don't forget to change to binary mode! or you will have a scrambled image!
            FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\casonkl\\Desktop\\my_downloaded_image_new_name.jpg");

      ftp.retrieveFile("name_of_image_on_server.jpg", br);
      ftp.disconnect();

     }
```

I m getting following error

> java.net.UnknownHostException: 172.17.178.144:2121

Comment: Can you ping 172.17.178.144?

Comment: Where does FTPClient come from? And are you sure you shouldn't give the port as a second argument?

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this, to set the port as separate parameter .

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect("172.17.178.144","2121");
ftpClient.connect(server, port);
```

Comment: Thanks fir Reply now I m able to connect whwn passing ip and port as two argument  like  ftp.connect("172.17.178.144",2121);  but I m not able to login through its giving out put                     1
2220 FTP server ready

login: false
3
Listed 0 files.